# ACF Taxonomy is blank / null

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF to add a 'names' category to my 'videos' custom post type.

I have added various names (taxonomies) to various video posts.

I'm using the following code in my Wordpress template and it does not work...

```
<?php 
$terms = get_field('names');
if( $terms ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
        <li>
            <h2><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo esc_html( $term->description ); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>">View all '<?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>' posts</a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...I just want to display all the names and then link to the specific video posts.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. Are you getting errors? What happens if you `var_dump( $terms )`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - it returns NULL

Comment: If you are trying to output those on the single template file for your custom video post type, then pass in the id of the video post and then var_dump again `$terms = get_field('names', get_the_ID());` Try that.

Comment: Still returning as NULL

Comment: Post images of how your fields are set up. In ACF and how they appear on your post type. If it's returning NULL, then something isn't set up correctly.

Comment: Looks from your screenshot like you should be using `$terms = get_field('add_names');` because your field is named `add_names` and not `name` but you can check all values from current post with `get_fields();` [get_fields() function doc](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: It wasn't a typo - I manage to get it working with $terms = get_terms('names'); - thanks for your help guys